# Frictional Force Acting On A Walking Dog

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, free-body-diagram

Recently I came across a free-body diagram that confused me. It is a dog attached to a leash that is held above and to the left of the dog. There is friction between the dog and the ground, however the free body diagram depicted the friction as being the force driving the dog forwards.

Normal View:

[image: Normal View]

Free Body Diagram:

[image: Free Body Diagram]

What I do not understand is why the friction force is being shown as the driving force of the dog, obviously the dogs paws are moving backwards relative to where the dog is move and therefore friction provides the force for the dog to move forward, however this would also mean that the forward force acting on the dog whenever the dog is moving is always the full force due to friction? Shouldn't the friction be depicted in the other direction, and another force be added to represent the forward force of the dog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dog is exerting a force backwards on the ground when attempting to walk. Per Newton's third law the ground exerts and equal and opposite static friction force  forward on the dog. If the dog were unleashed, that static friction force forward would be the only horizontal force acting on the dog enabling it to to accelerate forward. The same principle applies to the drive wheel of a car.

However, the dog does not move forward because the net horizontal force acting on the dog is zero. That is, the horizontal component of the force the leash exerts backwards on the dog is opposite and equal to the static friction force the ground exerts forward on the dog, for a net horizontal force of zero.

Hope this helps.